# cakephp find all primary column as key

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

When I fire this:

```
$this->model->find('all',array());
```

I get an array with the data of the model:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        // some data
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        // some data
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        // some data
    )
...
)
```

Now is it possible instead of 0,1,2 to get the id as key for each of the data?

For example:

```
Array
(
    [365] => Array
    (
        [model] => Array
        (
            [id] => 365     
            // some data
        )
    )
    [442] => Array
    (
        [model] => Array
        (
            [id] => 442     
            // some data
        )
    )
    [1000] => Array
    (
        [model] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1000     
            // some data
        )
    )
...
)
```

I know that `find('list')` can do something like that but only for 2 fields max (one key and one value).

Comment: _Is it possible to get the id as key for each of the data?_ No - not when you use the [find method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html).

Comment: I always appreciate downvotes without any comment whatsoever. Why tell the people what they did wrong so they won't do it again....

Answer (score 0):

you can build it maybe this code can do it :

```
$final_array = array();
foreach($returned_array as $k => $v){

    $final_array[$v['id']] = $v;
}
print_r($final_array);
```

Comment: I know that I can build it. But what I wanted was to get that array fully built.

Answer (score 0):

It's still an after-find operation but take a look at Set::combine (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html) as a more elegant solution. Something like:

```
$newArray = Set::combine($yourArray, '{n}.Model.id');
/* $newArray now looks like:
    Array
    (
        [365] =>
        [442] =>
        [1000] =>
    )
*/
```

(more or less just the the docs example) might work in your case.